# Interpret geometrically the equation

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The function $f$ is convex when:

$$f(tx+ (1-t)x', ty + (1-t)y') ≤  tf(x,y) + (1-t)f(x', y')$$

for all numbers $0≤t≤1$ and all pairs of points $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$ in the domain of $f$ (the whole of $R^2$)

How would I interpret this geometrically? Also what is an example of a convex function whose graph is not a plane?

Comment: Do you know the geometric interpretation of $tz_0+(1-t)z_1$ if $z_i$ are complex numbers and $t\in [0,1]$?

Comment: no, i've never heard that before. I'm not sure I have to use complex numbers for this question.

Comment: You don't have to, it's just a compact way to say it. You can break a complex number into real and imaginary part and get back to $x$'s and $y$'s any time. The interpretation is that **this yields the segment between $z_0$ and $z_1$ in the (complex) plane.**

Comment: Oh okay. I'm not completely sure what this means though, does this help with the question?

Comment: It's basically the only thing that you need to understand.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier Not necessarily a _complex_ plane. The definition given above doesn't mention 'complex'.

Comment: @Ciapan it doesn't matter, as I explained complex numbers simply allow for a compact formula.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It actually doesn't matter for you and for me. But **if** OP is not familiar with complex numbers and complex plane (as his/her comment indicates), then introduction of unnecessary notion may make the explanation more obscure instead of more clear.

Answer (score 1):

In $1$ dimension: 
$$
f(tx+(1-t)y)\le tf(x)+(1-t)f(y)
$$
[image]

$tx+(1-t)y, \; t \in [0;1]$ describes the line segment between $x$ and $y$ and $tf(x)+(1-t)f(y), \; t \in [0;1]$ describes the line segment between $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. So the inequality means that the image of the line segment $tx+(1-t)y$ (the green curve) lies beneath the line segment between the images of $x$ and $y$ (the pink curve).

Answer (score 0):

Parameter $t$ is a fraction corresponding to a relative position on a line segment.

Value $tx+(1−t)x′$ is a point in the interval $[x,x']$ chosen by $t$: it is $x'$ for $t=0$ and $x$ for $t=1$.
Similary, $ty+(1−t)y′$ is a corresponding point in the $[y,y']$ interval.

If we name the points $A(x,y)$ and $A'(x',y')$, we get a point in the $AA'$ segment
$$P=At+A'(1-t)$$

As a result, parameter $t$ on the LHS of the inequality defines a point at corresponding relative position of the $AA'$ line segment.

The RHS displays a similar relative division of the $f$ values' segment, corresponding to $A$ and $A'$.

Then the inequality, as a whole, says: the value of $f$ at any point $P$ of a line segment $AA'$ is not above the corresponding point of a chord between point $(A,f(A))$ and $(A',f(A'))$.

Comment: Could you describe the last line of what you wrote ( the 'Then the inequality, as a whole, says: the value of f at any point P of a line segment AA′ is not above the corresponding point of a chord between point (A,f(A)) and  (A′,f(A′))' in a little more detail? I'm a bit confused of what you mean by this.